# Issues connecting with server for postgres db - trying to understand why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on rails project which I've cloned from GitHub. Because of other commitments, I have not been able to program for ~6 months, so I may have had an OSX update in this time.

I am getting an issue which I see others have had:

```
➜  isengarden git:(develop) rails db:create
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'isengarden_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/joshua/code/JoshInLisbon/rails-projects/isengarden/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/joshua/code/JoshInLisbon/rails-projects/isengarden/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
./bin/rails:3:in `load'
./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

postgres.log:

```
2021-01-07 14:22:42.358 WET [86720] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2021-01-07 14:22:42.358 WET [86720] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 13.1.
```

I am trying the solutions that have been set out on StackOverflow, but I would really like to know what is going on under the hood to make this error happen.

I have quite a limited understanding of DB fundamentals, so for me a problem like this is in a very opaque space, where I'm just copying and pasting solutions without an idea of *why* they might work.

Can anyone explain what is likely happening, and what the actual meaning is of my postgres logs?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you're running a PostgreSQL version 13 on a versie 11 data directory. What updates did you do? And do you have other data directories?

Answer (score 1):

The version you have installed on your local computer is different from the postgres version with which the project was generated, when you change different versions you must be careful, since some functions are deprecated or renamed, in addition to the structure or form in which the data is saved also changes.

The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 13.1.

I suggest you install postgres version 11 and if you want to work with 13.1 then you must generate a backup and download it to a database generated with the current version

Comment: Thank you, so is postgres 'native' to my machine. So let's say I'm starting a project, and I create a postgres db which uses (say) v 11. Then I do a computer update and postgres is updated to v 13, there will be a natural conflict and things might break? Or am I understanding what is going on incorrectly?